# VHDL Array Initialization Error

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I have written simple code and defined only one array. but it shows following three errors.

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - Syntax error near "type". Parsing entity
>   .
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - Unit  ignored due to previous errors.
>   Parsing architecture  of entity .
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:374 -  Entity  is not yet compiled.

```
   library IEEE;
   use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

    type NIBBLE is ARRAY (3 downto 0) of std_ulogic;

    entity kelvin is
    end kelvin;

    architecture ospl of kelvin is
    begin
    end ospl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is illegal in VHDL to declare a `type` (or anything else) outside a *design unit* (ie outside an *entity*, *architecture*, *package* or *package body*). Furthermore, you have to declare a `type` (and anything else) inside a *declarative region* (ie between `architecture` and `begin` or between `process` and `begin` etc).

So, your code should be

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity kelvin is
end kelvin;

architecture ospl of kelvin is
  type NIBBLE is ARRAY (3 downto 0) of std_ulogic;
begin
```

Comment: Thank you for quickly Response. The Error I am getting now is ERROR:NgdBuild:605 - logical root block 'kelvin' with type 'kelvin' is
   unexpanded. Symbol 'kelvin' is not supported in target 'artix7'.

Comment: @KelvinKalariya You're welcome. If you have a further question, please post it as a new question. The idea of Stack Overflow is that questions should be useful to future viewers. A conversation will not be.